# Spring Java shuts down right after initializing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, mysql-connector

Hi everyone and tysm for your time :) This is my first Spring Java project and I'm using VSCode for it. When I initialize the app it shuts down right after as you can see in the log below. It's my first time using Spring and I honestly have no idea on how to tackle this problem (neither does ChatGPT). Just in case it is useful, I'll remark that the final aim of this project is to realize a POST petition via Postman to a database called db_cristianoronaldo which I have opened in MySQL Workbench. I was able to access the database before but not anymore.
Any help is appreciated :D Below you can find the terminal log when I run the app through the Spring Boot Dashboard, as well as the pom.xml and the application.properties:

```
09:24:25.356 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader
- Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@493f1ebe

  .   ____          _            __ _ _  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __
_ \ \ \ \ ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / / 
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.1)

2024-01-17 09:24:26.157  INFO 6016 --- [  restartedMain] com.tomadecontacto.demo.DemoApplication  : Starting DemoApplication using Java 11.0.19 on DESKTOP-970N2AP with PID 6016 (C:\Users\PortatilNovis\Documents\tomadecontactospring\demo\target\classes started by PortatilNovis in C:\Users\PortatilNovis\Documents\tomadecontactospring\demo) 2024-01-17 09:24:26.162  INFO 6016 --- [  restartedMain] com.tomadecontacto.demo.DemoApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default 2024-01-17 09:24:26.274  INFO 6016 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable 2024-01-17 09:24:27.515  INFO 6016 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data  JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode. 2024-01-17 09:24:27.598  INFO 6016
--- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 68 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces. 2024-01-17 09:24:28.411  INFO 6016 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default] 2024-01-17 09:24:28.512 INFO 6016 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                  : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.1.Final 2024-01-17 09:24:28.774  INFO 6016 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final} 2024-01-17 09:24:28.964  INFO 6016
--- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...2024-01-17 09:24:29.228  INFO 6016 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1
- Start completed. 2024-01-17 09:24:29.265  INFO 6016 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect:  org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect 2024-01-17 09:24:30.295  INFO 6016 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform] 2024-01-17 09:24:30.326  INFO 6016 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 2024-01-17 09:24:32.088  INFO 6016 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729 2024-01-17 09:24:32.142  INFO 6016 --- [  restartedMain] com.tomadecontacto.demo.DemoApplication  : Started DemoApplication in 6.76 seconds (JVM running for 8.549) 2024-01-17 09:24:32.168  INFO 6016 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 2024-01-17 09:24:32.177  INFO 6016 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated... 2024-01-17 09:24:32.203  INFO 6016 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">   
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <relativePath />   </parent>

  <groupId>com.tomadecontacto</groupId>   
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>   
<name>demo</name>   <description>Demo project for Spring 
Boot</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>   </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>   </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version> <!-- O la última versión disponible -->
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source> <!-- Ajusta según tu versión de Java -->
          <target>11</target> <!-- Ajusta según tu versión de Java -->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>   </build> </project>
```

application.properties:

> ```
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_cristianoronaldo?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Madrid
> spring.datasource.username=root 
> spring.datasource.password=1234 
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
> spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect 
> spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug 
> spring.devtools.restart.enabled=false 
> spring.devtools.enabled=false
> ```

Edit: thanks to the comments I was able to solve it :) The problem was in the dependencies of the pom (the spring-boot-web), so it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.tomadecontacto</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version> <!-- O la última versión disponible -->
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source> <!-- Ajusta según tu versión de Java -->
          <target>11</target> <!-- Ajusta según tu versión de Java -->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please don't use quotes for formatting code! There are code tags for that which will keep it readable. Currently it is totally  unreadadble. Also ditch the `jakarta.persistence-api` and `spring-web` dependency.

Comment: Sounds like you should rely on `spring-boot-starter-web` in stead of `spring-web`.  Now I guess there's no servlet container being autoconfigured, thus your application shuts down because there's no reason why it should keep running.

Comment: its also possible that OP used a try-with resources when running his SpringApplication. This will automatically close the context, stopping the application